# rewrite with argument under proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I have a proxy_pass for /d directory.

I wanted to write a rewrite rule for this, but i didn't find the right way to do it.

> /d/p.php?i=test
>
> needs to go
>
> /d/p/test

what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You can map $query_string to get the parameter into a variable, and then proxy_pass to /d/p/$variable; it's an option. First step is to get that "test2 into a variable that can be passed .

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one:

> location ^~ /miserableadm.php {
>
> rewrite ^/miserableadm.php$ http://TEST/path/$arg_select;
>
> }

And this is the result:

> curl -I -L http://TEST/miserableadm.php?select=8888
>
> HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
>
> Location: http://TEST/path/8888?u=8888

How can I get this work with one arg only?
It shows 8888?u=8888 in a strange way.